# SecurityProperties in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Trying to create an application with user authentication using JWT (JSON Web Tokens). However when I started configuring WebSecurityConfig.java I faced with the next issue:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    String[] permited = new String[security.getIgnored().size()];
    security.getIgnored().toArray(permited);

    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
                .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.headers().cacheControl();
}
```

And it shows me it "can't resovle method getIgnored()". This is just first a few stirngs at the begginig of this method.

I understood that there are 2 classes with same name in spring:

1) https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityProperties.html

2) https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityProperties.html

So I need the method getIgnored() from the second class. Please help me it this process. I understand that this might be a stupid question but I appreciate any help.

By the way, this is how I define "security" with @Autowired anotation:

```
@Autowired
SecurityProperties security;
```

Comment: You probably have a mess in your dependencies. You need to strictly take the ones from Spring Boot 2. You need to post your Pom in order for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not 2 differents classes, but the same at differents versions.

The `getIgnored` method has been removed see [Github commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/e08ddbf838a54e589c07e2be36153a3f330f9550#diff-de0d5f660d2c3c777afbac42e8b1eddf)

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!